# How can I pass variable with Ajax link in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, parameter-passing

I want to pass variable with link_to_remote in Rails 2.3. Following is my code for passing variable. But controller did not get that variable. Anybody can help me ?

```
<%= link_to_remote 'Add new event', :url => {:controller => 'events', :action => 'new' }, :with=> 'event' %><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any hash key you add that's not part of the keyword set (controller, action, format) will be appended to your URL as an argument.

ie.

`<%= link_to_remote "Add New Event", :url => {:controller => 'events', :action => 'new', :var => 'event'} %>`

Would yield

`/events/new?var=event`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would solve your problem,I have not tried.

> <%= link_to_remote "Add New event",
>   :url => :action => "list",
>   :with => " 'name=' +$('div-id-of-name-text-box').value + '&city=' +$('div-id-of-city-text-box').value + '&country=' +$('div-id-of-country-text-box').value " %>

Comment: How can I pass parameter with url?( :var=>'event' i want to add this into link_to_remote)